# C# - Application.EnableVisualStyles()

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Once `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` is used in Visual Studio 2010 (C#), can it be disabled and then re-enabled?

I like its appearance in some places, but not in others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Typically you call this once when your app starts (in the Main method), and then it's on for the application. You can't turn it off again.

However, you can choose not to use them for some forms - using the `VisualStyleState` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.visualstylestate.aspx

Comment: Added some info about VisualStyleState - hope you saw that!